# PHP PDO Delete older entries than 'x' (user defined) days

Tags: php, mysql, input, pdo

First of all, I started with PHP and databases like 1 month ago, but so far I found solutions to most of by problems googling.

I'm trying to make an admin function where you can delete entries older than 'X' days.
But I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with my PDO (the :day part).

PHP:

```
$backsite = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_POST['days'])) {
    $days = $_POST['days'];
    $statement = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL :days DAYS)");
    $statement->execute(array(':days' => $days));
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="' . $backsite .'">
    <input type="number" min="7" max="90" placeholder="7" required="" name="days"/>
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DAYS)' at line
>   1' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/skiss/archive.php:10 Stack
>   trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/skiss/archive.php(10):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/skiss/archive.php on line 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DAYS` needs to be singular.

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL :days DAY)
```

Comment: Wow.. lol. Yeah it's working now. Kinda embarrassing :p Thanks :)

Comment: @user1842128 heh, no worries, glad I could help ;)  You could always mark it correct, lol

Answer (score 0):

```
$backsite = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_POST['days'])) {
    $days = $_POST['days'];
   $statement = $db->prepare("[DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL :days DAY)](dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html)");
   $statement->execute(array(':days' => $days));
}
```

You had an extra "S" in your SQL statement.